# How to transform a one hot encoded dataframe to a basket sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform a one-hot-encoded dataframe into a basket sparse matrix.

I have this:

```
df
Ticket Number  Water  Orange  Lemon  Strawb.  Peach  Book  Pen
5001           0      0      0     0       1     1    0
5002           1      1      0     0       1     1    0
5003           1      0      0     0       0     0    0
```

I want this:

```
df
Ticket Number 
5001           Peach, Book
5002           Water, Orange, Peach, Book
5003           Water
```

I have tried some of the ideas here:

[Pivoting a One-Hot-Encode Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011881/pivoting-a-one-hot-encode-dataframe)

But I wasn't able to come up with a solution myself.

Some help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

[image: This is how the dataframe actually looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.dot` after setting "Ticket Number" to be the index:

```
u = df.set_index('Ticket Number')
u.dot(u.columns+',').str.rstrip(',')

Ticket Number
5001                 Peach,Book
5002    Water,Orange,Peach,Book
5003                      Water
dtype: object
```

Or,

```
u.dot(u.columns+',').str[:-1].reset_index(name='Items')

   Ticket Number                    Items
0           5001               Peach,Book
1           5002  Water,Orange,Peach,Book
2           5003                    Water
```

---

A slightly more robust version of the same thing:

```
u = df.set_index('Ticket Number').select_dtypes([np.number])
u = u.fillna(0, downcast='infer').clip(lower=0, upper=1)
u.dot(u.columns+',').str[:-1]

Ticket Number
5001                 Peach,Book
5002    Water,Orange,Peach,Book
5003                      Water
dtype: object
```

Comment: `df.dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]
`

Comment: For some reason i thought `.dot()` only worked with `bool` :(

Comment: @anky_91 It's work as long as its 0/1 in any form. Dot will "multiply" the string with the number. s * 0 is '' and s * 1 is s. That's the trick here.

Comment: Hi @WeNYoBen thanks for your effort. I am encountering this error: `
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: @Marc After `u = df.set_index('Ticket Number')`, do `u = u.fillna(0, downcast='infer')` and try the `dot` step again.

Comment: Hi @cs95 thank you very much for your help. I am still getting the same error. I don't understand why it isn't working!

Comment: @Marc Me neither... unless you can show me some data sample where this code is failing :)

Comment: @cs95 How can I share that with you?

Comment: @Marc Just [modify your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56277750/edit) to include 2-3 more rows with new data. Make sure you can reproduce the issue on the sample provided. Thanks!

Comment: @cs95 As suggested, I have included a screenshot of the actual dataframe before doing any modifications suggested here. I hope you can help and thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Marc Umm, okay, I've edited my answer and thrown the kitchen sink at it. If it doesn't work, don't forget to save your file. It'll work after that.

Comment: @cs95 Thanks for your time and help. I had some items that had values greater than 1, hence it didn't work. I appreciate your time and effort! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

A long way

```
df.melt('TicketNumber').loc[lambda x :x['value']==1].groupby('TicketNumber').variable.agg(','.join)
Out[746]: 
TicketNumber
5001                 Peach,Book
5002    Water,Orange,Peach,Book
5003                      Water
Name: variable, dtype: object
```